# Excel 2003: Trying to lock/hide individual sheets that can each have a different password

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, password-protection, excel-2003, vba

I am using Excel 2003.

I have a workbook with about 20 sheets in it.
1. I would like the workbook to always open up with the first 2 sheets either hidden or locked.
2. I would like an administrator to be able to unhide those sheets, when prompted for a password to unhide. Each sheet needs a different password.
3. After the administrator edits and saves and passes it to a normal user. When the normal user opens the file those 2 sheets should be hidden again just like in Step 1.

This code below seems to almost do what I want, but it only minimizes and maximizes the sheets. Instead of messing with the window I want the password to pop up with a lock on the sheet so it is never visible:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
If InputBox("Enter Password for this sheet") <> "ABC" Then Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Activate
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these snippets instead to hide and show respectively:

```
Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetVisible
```

Comment: I open the workbook, click the sheet that I want to be locked, it instantly hides and moves to the next sheet and asks for password, I put "ABC" in and then the sheet reappears down below. But when I click to view it it moves to the next sheet and asks for a password. I never get access to the sheet. `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    If InputBox("Enter Password for this sheet") <> "ABC" Then Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Activate
    Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetVisible
End Sub`

Comment: Here is my code: `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`<br/>
    `Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetHidden`<br/>
    `If InputBox("Enter Password for this sheet") <> "ABC" Then Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Activate`<br/>
    `Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetVisible`<br/>
`End Sub`

Comment: Sorry to bug you but do you have any idea why it never lets me into the sheet and I just keep repeating and repeating the process. It always prompts me for the password and never takes me in. Even though it unhides it.

Comment: Try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of the code and `Application.EnableEvents = True` again at the end, see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry I guess I suck at using Markdown I am putting it in a code block, but don't know how to do line-breaks. Still not working it prompts me for a password I type it in then it jumps to the next sheet then when I try to go back and view it prompts for the password again: `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    If InputBox("Enter Password for this sheet") <> "ABC" Then Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Activate
    Sheets("Cust. Pricing").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`